# checking cell number and clear the text from the textbox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is my problem I created a textbox to check U.S cellphone number and a function in JS that check numbers only. the problem is after I enter wrong number and I want to clear the textbox the function in JS won't let me it just delete everthing instad of using backspace and delete one char each time.It won't work on firefox why??? and when I click on star in the keyboard it deleting everything why is that????

This my code:

```
function NumbersOnly(sender, args) {
    var text = sender.get_value() + args.get_keyCharacter();
    if (!text.match('^[0-9]+$') && text != '\b' && text != '(' && text != ')' && text != '-') {
        args.set_cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Cell:

```
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left">
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" MaxLength="25" Width="200px"><ClientEvents OnKeyPress="NumbersOnly"></ClientEvents></telerik:RadTextBox>                
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="revPhone"
                            ControlToValidate="txtPhone"
                            Display="None"
                            ValidationExpression="^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$"
                            ValidationGroup="validateEditUser"
                            EnableClientScript="false"
                            ErrorMessage="- Please enter a valid phone number:(ex.) <b>(xxx-xxx-xxxx)</b></br>" />
        </tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why clearing the field doesn't work, but `text = sender.get_value() + args.get_keyCharacter();` definitely won't do the right thing given that the user may not be typing at the end of the field. Also there's not much point comparing the whole `text` value to `'('` and so forth, you'd need to compare each letter if such tests weren't already made redundant by a regex test for digits.

Comment: can you please help me with that? I want to clear the textbox by using the backspace but it won't work on firefox browser. and when I click on other keys in the keyboard it's deleting everything.